# what are the required Gem for Automated Acceptance testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, bdd

I want to write acceptance testing through cucumber and capybara. i have experience with rspec. I want to write **integration/features** test cases . I want outcome to be seen on a web browser which shows the test case running. what are the **gems** required for writing test cases .

Comment: I do this with rspec, but I guess minitest and cucumber do it too

Comment: i would also like to know doing this in the rspec way

Answer (score 1):

If you are already familiar with RSpec, I recommend you to use RSpec with Capybara for acceptance testing. RSpec is testing framework, and Capybara is a library that helps you to test web applications by simulating how a real user would interact with your app.

Acceptance tests in RSpec with Capybara are called "feature specs" and live in `/spec/features` directory in Rails. Capybara comes with a built in DSL for writing descriptive acceptance tests with RSpec (`feature/scenario`), but you may also use traditional RSpec DSL (`describe/it`).

Capybara supports several drivers, and its default driver RackTest doesn't support JavaScript. So, probably, you'll want to use one of the alternative drivers (I prefer Poltergeist, but it is headless, so if you want to see result in the browser, you may use Selenium driver). In this case, you'll need to set up [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) to clear your database between tests. [Capybara's](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) README contains a lot of information about its configuration and usage with RSpec, configuring driver and using database_cleaner.

You can start with [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara) and [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/391-testing-javascript-with-phantomjs) screencasts. But remember, that they are a little bit outdated and use traditional RSpec DSL (instead of new Capybara DSL), and use old convention, when "feature" specs were called "request" specs. Currently, by convention, "request" specs, are integration tests without capybara. So you'll need to create your capybara specs in `spec/features` directory, not `spec/requests`. And if you want to use Capybara DSL, this is easy to fix too. Just replace `describe` with `feature`, `it` with `scenario`, `let` with `given` etc. It is well documented in Capybara's README.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for sharing things. can you give me exact set of gem for that if i would like to go with rspec , capybara , selenium

Comment: You'll need at least "rspec-rails", "capybara" and "database_cleaner" for this.

Comment: how should i set Selenium driver

Comment: It will be used by default for javascript specs (which are marked with ":js => true")